# Java lambda expression requires unavoidable null

Tags: java, lambda, null, java-8

As Tony Hoare stated, `null` was an expensive failure and we try to avoid it nowadays. We finally got an official Optional with Java 8 and so we can almost entirely eliminate `null` from new Java programs.. almost.

I encountered a place, where I simply do not know how to avoid the usage of the dreaded `null` keyword and wondered if this is really unavoidable for now. Consider the following:

```
<T> T decorate(final Supplier<T> f) {
  // do something funny
  return f.get();
}
```

This little method is a way to decorate pretty much anything you can wrap into a lambda, so usage would look something like this:

`decorate(() -> obj.thatThing(x))`

I have used this construct quite successfully for timing observations, JMX updates, locks, etc. etc., but there is always the problem of `T = Void`:

```
decorate(() -> thatVoidMethod()); // won't compile
 decorate(() -> {
   thatVoidMethod();
   return null; // Is this really unavoidable?
 });
```

Anyone who can shed some light on this? Is there a chance we will see a smarter compiler for this in Java 9+? Am I just missing the simple solution?

Edit:

I'm not convinced of this being a duplicate yet, so let me try to address this in a bit more detail: 
The other question tries to create a `Function<T, Void>` similarly as I try to create a `Supplier<Void>`. The suggested and accepted solution is to use `return null`, but this question is about finding a different approach that does not require the `null` keyword.

The signature of my `thatVoidMethod` is simply `void thatVoidMethod()` and the `decorate` call is a way to add behavior before and/or after the code in `thatVoidMethod` being executed (similar to the Decorator pattern for whole classes, hence, the name).

As @zeroflagL stated, a problem really is that `Supplier<Void>` doesn't make much sense. That's one way of thinking of course, but in the Java language I cannot accept that, since side-effects are part of Java's nature. From a strong type system perspective a method `void f()` is equivalent to a no-op of course, but in Java-reality, we just have to deal with these methods doing meaningful stuff.

Therefore, I could rephrase the question alternatively to see if the `decorate` method can be written in a way that also supports such methods and also avoids usage of `null`. Of course, a `Runnable` as mentioned by the comments is another option, but with that, I cannot write a decoration method with the original method's return type. Here's an example usage of decorate in a little bit more context to highlight, why a `Runnable`-approach wouldn't work:

```
String calculateTheString() { return "whatever"; }
void performSideEffect() { ... }

// This works, but wouldn't work with a Runnable:
String doSomethingDecorated() {
  return decorate(this::calculateTheString);
}

// This would look nicer with a Runnable:
void performDecoratedSideEffect() {
  decorate(() -> {
    performSideEffect();
    return null;
  });
}
```

The other obvious solution of creating two methods, one for `Supplier` and one for `Runnable` also doesn't look very appealing, as you still need to duplicate the actual decoration code. (Thanks to @Holger for pointing out that overloading is indeed possible in this case.)

Comment: What is `thatVoidMethod()` signature exactly?

Comment: Why not overload the decorate method with a Runnable argument? `public void decorate(Runnable f)`.

Comment: @JBNizet Exactly. Because `void` isn't reference type, so it is impossible to make something more elegant than just overload method

Comment: "Is this really una**void**able?" genius :D Being serious: A `Supplier` is called so for a reason. A `void` method doesn't supply anything. So this is not really about lambda expressions, the compiler or `null`. You have a mismatch in the first place.

Comment: There is no ambiguity problem with overloading. A lambda expression of the form `() -> expression` can’t be a `Runnable` and a lambda of the form `() -> { statement }` can’t be a `Supplier` (unless it’s a `return` statement, but that also creates no ambiguity). In case of constructs that are both, statement and expression, like method invocations or `x++`, you just have to decide whether you use, e.g. `() -> { x++; }` to make it a statement (use `Runnable`) or `() -> ( x++ )` to make it an expression (use `Supplier`). Round brackets or curly brackets—that’s all.

Comment: And the answer of the linked question does not suggest to use `return null;`. It suggests to use `Consumer` instead of `Function` which is equivalent to use `Runnable` instead of `Supplier`. It only states that if you don’t do that, you have to use `return null;`.